# Code to find primary number in list and return it

Tags: python

I want to define a function to find primary numbers in a list and return the primary number in `alist` below the code but it returns empty lists. I need help to find what is wrong.

```py
def primes_nums(array):
  li=[]
  for num in array:
    if num > 1:
      for i in range(2, num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
          break
    elif num == 1:
        continue      
    else:
      li.append(num)
    print(li)
  return li

array=[1, 5, 2, 10]
print(primes_nums(array))
```

Comment: You'll never execute `li=li.append(num)` with your test case. Also, the code should be `li.append(num)` not `li = li.append(num)` because append doesn't return a value.

Comment: And please note that `.append` doesn't return anything.  It's just `li.append(num)`, once you move it to the right spot.

Comment: Consider what exactly 'else' means in your program's context.  If a number isn't greater than one (the if statement) or equal to one (the elif), then it must be less than one.  This means that as it is, your program is only considering negative numbers to be prime

Comment: As all prime numbers should fall into the 'greater than 1' case, the part of the code that handles adding them to the list will have to go inside the first if statement

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with your code is that for any `num > 1`, you just end up in this part of the code:

```py
for i in range(2, num):
  if (num % i) == 0:
    break
```

which actually never adds the number in the list, no matter how all the comparisons end. A possible solution of this might looks something like this:

```py
def primes_nums(array):
  li=[]
  for num in array:
    if num > 1:
      is_prime = True
      for i in range(2, num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
          is_prime = False
      if is_prime:
        li.append(num)
    elif num == 1:
        continue
  return li

array=[1, 5, 2, 10]
print(primes_nums(array))
```

Also, you do not need to use `li=li.append(num)`, as `append` just modifies the existing list.

Comment: sorry i do not understand  the is_prime part

Comment: @QuackE.Duck You are right, I missed that, edited the answer.

Comment: The key point here is that you cannot say a number is prime until you have tries ALL the possible factors.  Thus, you can't just `break` the loop, because when the loop ends, you won't know whether you had a hit or not.  The `is_prime` flag is one solution.  It stays True until we find out that the number is not prime.  I solved that in my solution by using `break` and the relatively little-known `else` clause in the `for` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, all you need to do is move the "else" so it is part of the "for".  The "else" clause of a "for" statement gets executed if you get all the way through the loop without using "break".  In this case, that only happens if you try all of the factors and none of them matches.

Also note that you don't have to search all the way to `num`.  You can stop at `num//2`.  Technically, you can stop at `math.sqrt(num)+1`, but that's an optimization for later.

```
def primes_nums(array):
  li=[]
  for num in array:
    if num > 1:
      for i in range(2, num//2+1):
        if (num % i) == 0:
          break
      else:
        li.append(num)
    elif num == 1:
        continue      
  print(li)
  return li
```

Comment: The range specification is more than an optimisation. num//2 will result in 4 being erroneously considered to be a prime number. int(num**0.5)+1 would be better

Comment: If we're going to invoke floating math anyway, we might as well do the `math.sqrt` option.  Sqrt is not that much more expensive.

Comment: If we're going to invoke floating math anyway, we might as well do the `math.sqrt` option.  Sqrt is not that much more expensive.